# Convert SQLAlchemy Column type to Python data type respecting variant

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have added support for sqlite in some of my SQLAlchemy models, so some columns appear with variants based on the dialect

```
dt = Column(DateTime().with_variant(String, 'sqlite'))
```

I have a logic that relies on the python data type for that field, such as  `col.type.python_type` but this now returns `Variant`, in which the `python_type` attribute raise `NotImplementedError`.

In my code I already know whether my engine is based off `sqlite` or `sqlserver`, so is there a way to tell sqlalchemy to give me the `.type.python_type` for the dialect that I am using instead of returning `Variant`?

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you need to set the variant ? SQLite's datetime is already a string ?

Comment: @ljmc good question!  Unfortuantely sqlalchemy ``datetime`` field for sqlite insists on taking a python ``datetime`` object for insertion, and always return ``datetime`` when reading from the db.  In contrast sqlserver dialect happilly accepts either ``datetime`` or ``str`` in the isoformat, and I cannot change the entire codebase from datetime strings to datetime objects.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have used an extension of the original [DB-API spec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/) when you used ISO 8601 strings as input for datetime.

This extension is a nicety and is available in MSSQL and PG as far I have checked, but not in the SQLite DB-API.

The `DateTime().with_variant(String, 'sqlite')` variant appears to fall back to the `python_type` implementation of `TypeEngine`, which raises a `NotImplementedError` as it is not implemented on that `TypeEngine`, but rather on the types which inherit from `TypeEngine`.

Please add more of your code so we can understand better your reliance on the `python_type` property.

@gord-thompson or @snakecharmerb might have more insight.